# deleting all images from http response's entity in java

Tags: java, string, http, tags, entity

I have http body in which I want to remove all the image tags. For example from a response which has the entity:

```
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(
            "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
            "<html>\n" +
                "<head>\n" + 
                    "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n" + 
                    "<title>Title of the document</title>\n" +
                "</head>\n" +
                    "<body>\n"
                    + "Content of the document..\n" +
                        "<img src=\"image\">\n" + 
                    "</body>\n" +
            "</html>");
```

I tried the following but it didn't change:

```
        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
        responseString.replaceAll("<img .*?>","");
```

Comment: Try removing the question mark? If I'm not mistaken, a question mark indicates the end of line.